# How to get read_html to loop? Python

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

I currently have the following code, the df2 = df[0] restricts the code to only gather data for 1 game on that corresponding date. I am trying to figure out how to gather multiple games data that took place on the same day.

Idea is to extract match data for all games taken place on one day and continue running for entire page

E.g. 
tables[20]
returns to html links

1) href="/matches/2338970/north-vs-mad-lions-dreamhack-open-leipzig-2020

2) href="/matches/2338968/heroic-vs-mad-lions-dreamhack-open-leipzig-2020

I have tried the following:

```
for i in range(len(df2)):
  df2[i] = df2[i]
```

but it doesnt update each variable (teamchosen, choose, maps) instead just repeats the first matches data across the other matches (see picture)[image]

```
team_id = 8362
for i in range(0,1):
    i = i*100
    url = "https://www.hltv.org/results?offset={}&team={}".format(i,team_id)

    res = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')

    tables = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "results-sublist"})


    index = 0
    list_dfs = []
    for table in tables:
        df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["match", "teamchoose", "chosen", "maps", "team", "opponent", "date"])
        df2 = pd.read_html(str(table))

        df2 = df2[0]

        link = table.find('a', href=True)
        link = "https://www.hltv.org/" + link.get('href')
        res = requests.get(link)
        soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
        temp = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "padding"})
        date = date = pd.to_datetime(int(soup.select(".timeAndEvent div")[0]['data-unix'])*1000000)

        out = re.findall(r'<div>\d\.(.*?)</div>', str(temp))

        dict_choices = {"teamchoose": [], "chosen": [], "maps": []}
        for choice in out[0:6]:
            split = choice.strip(" ").split(" ")
            dict_choices["teamchoose"].append(" ".join(split[:-2]))
            dict_choices["chosen"].append(split[-2])
            dict_choices["maps"].append(split[-1])
                # df = df.append(dict_choices, True)
                # dict_choices = {"turn": [], "choice": [], "maps": []}
        try:
            left = out[6]
            split = left.strip(" ").split(" ")
            dict_choices["teamchoose"].append(split[2])
            dict_choices["chosen"].append(split[2])
            dict_choices["maps"].append(split[0])
        except:
            pass
        df = df.append(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_choices, orient='index').transpose())

        df["opponent"] = df2[2].iloc[0]
        df["team"] = df2[0].iloc[0]
        df["match"] = index
        df['date'] = date
        list_dfs.append(df)
        index +=1


df_out = pd.concat(list_dfs)
df_out = df_out[['match','date','team','opponent','teamchoose','chosen','maps']]
df_out.to_csv("{}_vetoes.csv".format(team_name),index=False)
print(tabulate(df_out, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))
```

Comment: provide team_id part of the code

Comment: 8362  @chitown88 added to code as well

Comment: I'm a little unclear about what the issue is. What is the expected output suppose to look like? You're code is running exactly how it's written to do it. Si I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: So basically, df[0] makes it only take the first game, if 2+ games have occured today then it will only scrape the first game and not the second, I want to make it so it scrapes both games.. hence it loops through all games on each day scraping data. If you see tables[20] there are two games that day but the code only scrapes the first, I cant edit it so it scrapes both games

Comment: so there needs to be a for loop between df2 =pd.read_html and df2=df2[0] to make sure if there is more than 1 game on in a day it scrapes all games instead of the first game @chitown88

Comment: ahhh. ok. I see what you're saying.Ya, I'll work out that logic to iterate through that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. So you just need to loop through the sub tables it pull form the tables. Also, I made one other change. Instead of setting `index = 0` then increment after each loop, you can use `enumerate()` which will do that sort of for you. See if this works:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'}
team_id = 8362
for i in range(0,1):
    i = i*100
    url = "https://www.hltv.org/results?offset={}&team={}".format(i,team_id)

    res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = bs(res.content, 'html.parser')

    tables = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "results-sublist"})



    list_dfs = []
    for index, table in enumerate(tables):
        print ('Page %s:\t%s of %s' %(i+1, index+1, len(tables)))
        dfs = pd.read_html(str(table)) #<--- returns all the tables into a list called dfs
        for tableIdx, df2 in enumerate(dfs):  #<---- add additional loop here
            df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["match", "teamchoose", "chosen", "maps", "team", "opponent", "date"])
            link = table.find_all('a', href=True)[tableIdx]   #<--- Also need to grab correct link for associated table/match if there are more than 1 match
            link = "https://www.hltv.org/" + link.get('href')
            res = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
            soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
            temp = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "padding"})
            date = pd.to_datetime(int(soup.select(".timeAndEvent div")[0]['data-unix'])*1000000)

            out = re.findall(r'<div>\d\.(.*?)</div>', str(temp))

            dict_choices = {"teamchoose": [], "chosen": [], "maps": []}
            for choice in out[0:6]:
                split = choice.strip(" ").split(" ")
                dict_choices["teamchoose"].append(" ".join(split[:-2]))
                dict_choices["chosen"].append(split[-2])
                dict_choices["maps"].append(split[-1])
                    # df = df.append(dict_choices, True)
                    # dict_choices = {"turn": [], "choice": [], "maps": []}
            try:
                left = out[6]
                split = left.strip(" ").split(" ")
                dict_choices["teamchoose"].append(split[2])
                dict_choices["chosen"].append(split[2])
                dict_choices["maps"].append(split[0])
            except:
                pass
            df = df.append(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_choices, orient='index').transpose())

            df["opponent"] = df2[2].iloc[0]
            df["team"] = df2[0].iloc[0]
            df["match"] = index
            df['date'] = date
            list_dfs.append(df)



df_out = pd.concat(list_dfs)
df_out = df_out[['match','date','team','opponent','teamchoose','chosen','maps']]
df_out.to_csv("{}_vetoes.csv".format(team_name),index=False)
print(tabulate(df_out, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to update the variables as well (teamchoose, chosen and maps), as in some cases it still duplicates the first matches results..e.g. 24/01/2020 there were two games north and heroic.. for heroic it is giving north games data

Comment: ok. let me look at that. that's index 20, right? I think i saw 2 tables/matches, but I didn't look at the output.

Comment: yeah thats right, also i just ran it and some games are getting duplicated?

Comment: try it again and Let me know (you have a better understanding if it looks correct)